# Detecting css-content induced changes

Tags: html, css, mutation-observers, css-content

Suppose we have some CSS which adds text via `content:`, like:

```
:after {
  content: "Something";
}
```

It seems `MutationObserver` is blind to text changes induced by such `content` CSS elements. The text is also unselectable. It seems the `content`-added text is not part of the DOM. Where does it live then? What is the proper terminology to describe it?

More importantly, is it somehow accessible programmatically?

Here's a small experiment:

```js
setInterval(function test() {
  var x = document.querySelector("#x");
  if (x.innerText.indexOf("Something") != -1) {
    console.log(Date.now() + ":   SOMETHING !");
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
#x:hover:after {
  content: "Something";
}
```

```html
<div id="x">Test</div>
```

Comment: CSS :after and :before pseudo-classes aren't part of the DOM.

Comment: "The content CSS property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted using the content property are *anonymous replaced elements*." See [content @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).

Comment: Also see this Mozilla bug report: [Provide a way to observe mutations for ::before/::after pseudo elements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1034110).

Comment: @showdev thanks. So IIUC this is actually possible on recent chrome versions?  (https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/c883834a0a0e)

Comment: I'm not sure. It doesn't seem so. It might not be what I thought it was. The mutation only fires "when a native anonymous root is bound or unbound", which doesn't seem as relevant as I thought.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and couldn't make anything out of it... What's a native anonymous root?  How can it be in any state but bound or unbound?